# Syntax for javascript object implementing an AJAX GET and custom event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a couple of questions about this small snippett adapted from a tutorial I found [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/load-templates-external-files).

```
var loader = (function ($, host) {
    return {
        loadTemplate: function (path) {
            var tmplLoader = $.get(path)
                    .success(function (result) {
                        $("body").append(result);
                    })
                    .error(function (result) {
                        alert("Error Loading Template");
                    }) // --> (1) SEMICOLON?

            // (2) How does this wire up an event to the previous 
            // jQuery AJAX GET?  Didn't it already happen?
            tmplLoader.complete(function () {
                $(host).trigger("TemplateLoaded", [path]);
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery, document);
```

1. Is there supposed to be a semicolon there?
2. It seems like the AJAX GET is happening and *then* an event is getting wired to it - what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there supposed to be a semicolon there?

It's optional, but recommended.

> It seems like the AJAX GET is happening and then an event is getting wired to it - what am I missing here?

AJAX is asynchronous, so it's very unlikely the request will be already completed right after sending it. So, there's time to add another callback. And even if there weren't, it would work anyway, since jQuery implements those callbacks with [promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). See [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/39NSm/).

Comment: oh thanks for the revision about jquery promises - that truly answers my second question

Answer (score 2):

With javascript, and ajax in particular it is important to understand how the browser goes about executing your code. When you make the request for remote data via an ajax GET, the rest of your code is still executing. Imagine if as soon as you made a request for some JSON to a busy server, lets say it takes a couple seconds, and everything on your page stops working during that time period. It would be very difficult to write code that wasn't difficult for the user to interact with. Luckily ajax is async, meaning it makes the request and an carries on as usual until the complete event (or equivalent) is fired. This is what executes your code pertinent to the data you just received. So when you specify that callback at the bottom of your snippit, you are telling the browser, "go do your thing for now but when you hear back from the server, do all of these things".

Oh yeah, and semicolons are optional, but as a best practice, most people use them.

Answer (score 1):

They are assigning the $.get to a variable and then adding a complete handler to it.

It's the same as doing this:

```
$.get('/path'), function(){
  //success callback
}).error(function(e){
  //errors
}).complete(function(){
  //always run
});
```

Just an unusual way of doing it.